# Slice array at chosen point and choose one before and after inclusive

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

A user can choose a letter, I then want to assign what they've chosen, and one value either side to variables.

E.g. user chooses "c" produces:

```
$userVariable = 'c';

$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

// do something to $input and produce

$letter1 = 'b';
$letter2 = 'c';
$letter3 = 'd';
```

I'm guessing `array_slice()` but from reading up on it I cannot find a way it can select values before and after and indeed seems to "slice" at a numeric value as opposed to actualy value.

Also, if "a" is chosen then I need to return `a,b,c` and if "e" is chosen i want to return `e,d,c`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$userVariable = 'e';
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");    

// get position of $userVar in $input
$pos = array_search($userVariable,$input);
if($pos == 0){
    // the first one
    $letter1 = $input[$pos];
    $letter2 = $input[$pos+1];
    $letter3 = $input[$pos+2];
}elseif($pos==count($input)-1){
    // the last one
    $letter1 = $input[$pos-2];
    $letter2 = $input[$pos-1];
    $letter3 = $input[$pos];
}else{
    // others
    $letter1 = $input[$pos-1];
    $letter2 = $input[$pos];
    $letter3 = $input[$pos+1];
}
var_dump($letter1,$letter2,$letter3);

?>
```

Comment: @AncientGeek, It's not a copy, and your answer `===` is more better!I've voted your answer up.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$find = 'c';
$key = array_search($find, $input); //get the key index of user input
echo $key;  
echo '<br />';
$total = count($input);

if ( $key === 0)
{
    echo $input[$key];
    echo $input[$key+1];
    echo $input[$key+2];
}
else if( $key === ($total-1) )
{
   echo $input[$key-2];
   echo $input[$key-1];
   echo $input[$key];
}
else
{
   echo $input[$key-1];
   echo $input[$key];
   echo $input[$key+1];
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$userChoice="c";

for ($i=0; $i<count($input); $i++)
{
    if ($input[$i]==$userChoice)
    {
        $letter1=$input[$i-1];
        $letter2=$input[$i];
        $letter3=$input[$i+1];
    }
}

echo "Letter 1: ".$letter1."<br />";
echo "Letter 2: ".$letter2."<br />";
echo "Letter 3: ".$letter3;
```

Comment: Note that this will give an array index out of bounds error if the user chooses "a" or "e." I'll let you handle that as you will.

Answer (score 0):

First get index of the array value they key in

```
$key = array_search('c', $input );
```

then

```
if(isset($input[$key-1]))
$letter1 = $input[$key-1];

$letter2 = $input[$key];
if(isset($input[$key+1]))
$letter3 = $input[$key+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $userVariable = 'c';
    $input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

    foreach ($input as $idx => $value) {
        if ($userVariable == $value) {
            if ($idx == 0) {
                print $input[$idx] . "," .$input[$idx+1] . "," .$input[$idx+1];
            } else {
                if ($idx == count($input) - 1) {
                    print $input[$idx-2] . "," .$input[$idx-1] . "," .$input[$idx];
                } else {
                    print $input[$idx-1] . "," .$input[$idx] . "," .$input[$idx+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$key = array_search('a', $input);

echo $prev = (isset($input[$key - 1]))?$input[$key - 1]:"";
echo $selected = $input[$key];
echo $next = (isset($input[$key + 1]))?$input[$key + 1]:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_slice():

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$choice = 'e';

$result = array_slice(
    $input,
    ((array_search($choice, $input) - 1) > 0) ? array_search($choice, $input) - 1 : 0,
    3
);
var_dump($result);
```

though it doesn't give `e,d,c` if `e` is chosen, just `d,e`